# How to get file size from AWS S3 "ObjectRemoved:Delete" event

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs

**Background**

I'm storing some files (objects) in S3 bucket.
Whenever any file gets deleted from S3 bucket my Lambda function gets triggered.
The lambda function needs to subtract the object size from DynamoDB.

**Problem:**
S3 deleteObject event does not send object **Size**

**Sample S3 deleteObject event**

```
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "eventVersion": "2.0",
      "eventTime": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "requestParameters": {
        "sourceIPAddress": "127.0.0.1"
      },
      "s3": {
        "configurationId": "testConfigRule",
        "object": {
          "sequencer": "0A1B2C3D4E5F678901",
          "key": "HappyFace.jpg"
        },
        "bucket": {
          "arn": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket",
          "name": "sourcebucket",
          "ownerIdentity": {
            "principalId": "EXAMPLE"
          }
        },
        "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0"
      },
      "responseElements": {
        "x-amz-id-2": "EXAMPLE123/5678abcdefghijklambdaisawesome/mnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGH",
        "x-amz-request-id": "EXAMPLE123456789"
      },
      "awsRegion": "us-east-1",
      "eventName": "ObjectRemoved:Delete",
      "userIdentity": {
        "principalId": "EXAMPLE"
      },
      "eventSource": "aws:s3"
    }
  ]
}
```

Please help me find solution for my use case.

Comment: You could store the object size in DynamoDB when an object is uploaded and then retrieve that data when the object deleted notification happens. Not sure what your underlying need is here, but if it's simply to maintain an accurate bucket size or object count then you can use S3 metrics via CloudWatch for that.

Comment: Thanks Jarmod, For doing that do I need to set FileName as ID (Hash) of DynamoDB table? Because I will receive only filename from the deleteObject event which can be used to retrieve file details.

Comment: You can use the object key (not quite the same thing as a filename) and that would be simple. Unless you have many millions of objects and a very high deletion frequency, in which case you would want to consider a hash of the object key.

Comment: Thanks jarmod, I resolved the issue for now by creating DynamoDB file entry table.

Answer (score 1):

A way to do it is to enable versioning and [check the metadata of the last version](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RetMetaOfObjVersion.html).

To avoid having the deleted version forever, you could setup an expiration policy or [explicitly delete the version](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/DeletingObjectVersions.html). I'd probably use both to catch cases where the event processor (the lambda function) fails and could not delete the file.

Comment: Thanks Javier, Thought of that approach but don't you think that it will substantially increase the cost of S3 ?

Comment: It's hard to say for me. Which % of objects are deleted daily? If the event processor can delete the version, it would be a very short extra time.

Comment: Hi Javier, I have end up using approach suggested by you, Thanks